# Efficiency using bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

The requirement is like following:

```
/* length must be >= 18 */

int calcActualLength(int length) {
    int remainder = (length - 18) % 8;
    if (remainder == 0)
        return length;
    return length + 8 - remainder;
}
```

using bit-wise operator, I could refactor the 1st line

```
int remainder = (length - 2) & 7;
```

Can it be further optimized?

Comment: Unless your compiler is brain-dead, it will almost certainly optimise better than mere mortals can :-)

Comment: Why do you think you even need to "optimize" this particular function ? Have you *profiled* it and identified a performance issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"? If you mean improve runtime, I suspect you're trying to solve the wrong problem, and you'll have better luck twiddling compiler switches than trying to micro-optimize a function. That said, if you really want to optimize this function, I suspect your best bet will be to dive into the assembly code and optimize there; you might be able to trim out a superfluous operation or two. You'll probably also find your refactoring makes no difference to the resultant assembly code.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Well, in this case the compiler doesn't know that the value can't be negative, which is information that the writer has.  This is important for, for example, replacing the `% 8` with `& 7`.

Comment: this function returns 10 for length 10, 2 for length 2?

Comment: @perreal: This function isn't called for length 10 or length 2.

Comment: It appears you know the values won't be negative; therefore, *use* `unsigned int`s. It will allow the compiler to do many more optimizations.

Comment: In all cases, the function-call overhead will have a bigger impact on the performance than these trivial computations. To avoid that, you could *at least* inline the function.

Comment: You should focus on readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((length+5)&~7)+2`

```
int calcActualLength(int length) {
    int remainder = (length - 18) % 8;
    if (remainder == 0)
        return length;
    return length + 8 - remainder;
}
==>
int HELPER_calcActualLength(int length) {
    int remainder = length % 8;
    if (remainder == 0)
        return length;
    return length + 8 - remainder;
}
int calcActualLength(int length) {
    return 18 + HELPER_calcActualLength(length - 18);
}
```

And `HELPER_calcActualLength()` equals to `ROUNDUP_8()` in the semantics when the argument >= 0

And more simpler ROUNDUP_8() can be:

```
#define ROUNDUP_8(x) (((x)+7)&~7)

int calcActualLength(int length) {
    return 18 + ROUNDUP_8(length - 18);
}
==>    2 + ROUNDUP_8(length - 18 + 16);
==>    2 + ROUNDUP_8(length - 2);
==>    2 + (((length - 2)+7)&~7)
==>    ((length+5)&~7)+2
```

Answer (score 2):

Original code produces the following 64-bit assembly when compiling with `gcc -O3`:

```
        movl    %edi, %eax
        leal    -18(%rax), %ecx
        movl    %ecx, %edx
        sarl    $31, %edx
        shrl    $29, %edx
        addl    %edx, %ecx
        andl    $7, %ecx
        subl    %edx, %ecx
        je      .L2
        addl    $8, %eax
        subl    %ecx, %eax
.L2:
        rep
```

As suggested in the comments to your question, changing the argument to `unsigned int` allows for greater optimisations and results in the following assembly:

```
        leal    -18(%rdi), %edx
        movl    %edi, %eax
        andl    $7, %edx
        je      .L3
        leal    8(%rdi), %eax
        subl    %edx, %eax
.L3:
        rep
```

Rounding up to a multiple of `8` can be performed by adding `7` and masking with `~7`. It works like this: if the last three bits are not all zero, then adding `7` carries into the 4-th bit, otherwise no carry occurs. So your function could be simplified to:

```
return (((length - 18) + 7) & ~7) + 18;
```

or simpler:

```
return ((length - 11) & ~7) + 18;
```

GCC compiles the last line to simply:

```
        leal    -11(%rdi), %eax
        andl    $-8, %eax
        addl    $18, %eax
```

Note that the `lea` (Load Effective Address) instruciton is often "abused" for its ability to compute simple linear combinations like `reg1 + size*reg2 + offset`